# Java java.lang.ClassCastException thrown when referencing Firebase

Tags: java, firebase, classcastexception

I'm fairly new at Java and I've been having trouble resolving an exception I've been receiving.

First, here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "FirebaseEventTarget" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer 
at CallServer$1.onDataChange(CallServer.java:30)
at com.firebase.client.core.ValueListenerContainer$1.run(ValueListenerContainer.jav‌​a:47)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:8‌​86)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Here is the code.

```
public class CallServer {
     public void displayNameWeight(int adress){ 
// x = card name, displays card name and weight     
        String url = "https://dominion-randomizer.firebaseio.com/Set/Base/"
                + adress ;
        Firebase referenceCard = new Firebase(url);


        referenceCard.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override

            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snap) {

                Object value = snap.getValue();
/*Line 30*/     String name = (String) ((Map) value).get("name");
                Long weight = (Long)((Map)value).get("weight");

                System.out.println(name + "'s weight is:" + weight);

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError arg) {
                System.err.println("oops");
            }
        });
    }
    public void writeWeight(int adress, int weight)  {

        String url = "https://dominion-randomizer.firebaseio.com/Set/Base/"
                + adress;
        Firebase referenceCard = new Firebase(url);

        System.out.println("Card ID:" + adress);

        referenceCard.child("weight").setValue(weight);     

   }
```

So my problem is that when I use the displayNameWeight method, it functions correctly, however when I try to use writeWeight in conjunction with displayNameWeight, I get a java.lang.ClassCastException. I understand that I can't cast a different kinds of Objects together, however I don't understand why the first method functions correctly and the second one does not. The only thing I can think of is that when I reference the Firebase url, the Object type is somehow getting changed.

I apologize for my question not necessarily being coherent, I'm very new to programming.
 Edit:Showing line 30

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Just added it to the question with some formatting for readability if that's cool with you.

Comment: The actual "weight" entry in `value` is an `Integer` object, not a `Long` object.  Presumably there's a difference in the function that's creating/populating the `value` object.

Comment: (For future reference:  Always include a copy/paste of any error message, including at least the first few lines of traceback, if available.  And where a line number is present in the message, somehow identify that line in your include listing.)

Comment: Sorry about the formatting errors. I've added the line reference and the trace has been added to my post. I have an update. I added a catch for the specific exception, and the data is updated perfectly fine on the Firebase database side. This the code I added.           ` } catch (java.lang.ClassCastException e) { }`                        So I'm catching the exception and not doing anything with it which makes my code functional, however I would still to figure out why the exception is being thrown in the first place. I'm going to read a little more into the Firebase API.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than casting weight as you pull it out of the map, try pulling it out as an Object and then checking to see what type it is.

Or, instead of turning the entire snapshot into a Map, you could do the following:

```
Long weight = snap.child("weight").getValue(Long.class);
```

That might be a bit easier to read. In general, I would say take a look at the docs for DataSnapshot, there are several utility methods that make it easier to work with as opposed to a Map with no specified types for keys and values: https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/DataSnapshot.html